Is it possible to prove with high certainty part of a preimage must exist to produce an LtHash output?
Given a H calculated using the LtHash algorithm, is it possible to prove a section of the preimage must have been part of the specific original preimage?
i.e. given H = lt(A | X | B) give proof that X was part of the preimage where A and B must be the fixed specific values and not simply calculable given X and H
For the purposes of my problem the offset position of X is known or could be rearranged to be the beginning of the preimage eg. I = X | A | B
If i am barking up the wrong tree and lthash would not satisfy this requirement, i would like to know if it is possible to have an hashing scheme with the same quality of lthash, that the hash can be cheaply updated computation wise, that will fit the bill.
Thanks! ( :

You're exploring the properties of the LtHash algorithm, specifically its ability to prove a section of the preimage was part of the original preimage.
LtHash is a linear-time hash function, designed for efficient updates. However, regarding your question, LtHash does not provide a direct way to prove a section of the preimage was part of the original preimage.
LtHash limitations:

LtHash is a linear hash function, meaning it processes the input sequentially.
The hash value is computed using a combination of bitwise operations (XOR, AND, OR) and rotations.
LtHash is designed for efficient updates, but it does not provide any inherent proof of inclusion for a specific section of the preimage.

Proving inclusion of a section:
To prove that X was part of the original preimage, you would need a hash function with additional properties, such as:

Homomorphic hashing: allows computations on the hash value to correspond to computations on the input.
Proof-of-inclusion: enables verification that a specific section was part of the original input.

Some alternative hashing schemes that might satisfy your requirements:

Merkle Trees: a data structure that allows proof-of-inclusion and proof-of-absence.
Hash functions with homomorphic properties: e.g., Homomorphic Hashing (HH), or Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA)-based constructions.
Authenticated encryption modes: like AES-GCM or AES-OCB, which provide proof-of-inclusion.

Updating hash values efficiently:
To maintain efficient updates while using these alternative schemes, consider:

Incremental hashing: update hash values using only the changed parts of the input.
Hash chaining: compute hash values for smaller chunks of data and combine them.

Some specific constructions that balance efficiency and proof-of-inclusion:

Merkle Tree-based LtHash: combines LtHash with Merkle Tree properties.
Homomorphic LtHash: modifies LtHash to support homomorphic operations.

Keep in mind that these alternatives might have different performance characteristics and security guarantees compared to LtHash.
Recommendations:

Study Merkle Trees and homomorphic hashing to understand their properties.
Explore authenticated encryption modes for potential applications.
Consider modifying LtHash to incorporate homomorphic properties or proof-of-inclusion.

Would you like me to elaborate on any of these points or provide more information on specific constructions?

amazing! thanks! yes i would love to know more about how homomorphic schemes would accomplish this. i understand how compact merkle inclusion proofs work with non-lthash schemes so i imagine it is the same, but if not then more info on that would be great too!
